# How can I merge two XML files in Perl?

Tags: xml, perl

UPDATE:

Let me go into more details (as requested)

I have 2 Perl files, the first one generates a XML request/POST (No file is made). 
The second file is new and intended to add another element inside of the XML on certain conditions. The problem I'm having is the first file already checks for the conditions but the second file is needed to generate the new XML. How do I add the XML to the first file from the second file?

something like this:

(File #3 uses File #1)

```
use file1

my $xml = File1->new();

# Set some properties

# Now adding XML from file #2
my $addXML = File2->new();

# Set some more properties

# File1 needs to check if the XML or Object from File2 
# exists to add the XML to File1, else throw error.
```

I hope this helps and sorry for the first post.

Comment: Providing a short code sample does wonders for opening what's in your mind to others. I have no idea what you are trying to do. What is the **this** you are talking about?

Comment: sry most of the code I develop is in house and sharing it is NOT an option, as well as making suedo code can be cumbersome as well. Will try to do better, sry again :(

Comment: I can't undestand what `how do I check in person.pm for the me object` means. Can you add more detailed explanations about what is `me object` and what exactly do you need to check?

Comment: If sharing is not an option, I think helping is not an option. However, we don't need to see your production code. Make a very short but complete program that shows what you are trying to do. Test your ideas outside the production codebase before you add them. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming here that both "File1" and "File2" are purely object-oriented modules, meaning for this purpose that they do not maintain global state and only support class methods for creating objects and object methods for performing actions on those objects.

In this case, I'd put the checking logic in your main program, not in the File1 module, and write it like so:

```
if ($addXML->hasObjectImLookingFor) {
     $xml->add($addXML->getObjectImLookingFor);
} else {
     die "File 2 does not contain object I'm looking for";
}
```

I'm sorry this is vague, but honestly, so is your question. If you can actually give us a small sample of complete Perl code (I understand it can't be your real code, but just a small dummy module that illustrates the behavior) that might help.

Comment: I think I get what you're saying, took what you had and modified it to work. Thanks